# Android Google Map show blank screen

Tags: java, google-maps, android-studio

i start android studio with the default google map : 
[image]

add my key in google_maps_api.xml and i am sure about path:
[image]

this is my manifast:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.erfan.google">

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.


    -->


    <permission
        android:name="com.example.erfan.google.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.erfan.google.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

main activity :

```
package com.example.erfan.google;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

where i wrong ? try so many suggestions in another post in stack over flow but not work for me :( still blank google map :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you must to go [https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials](http://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) and after your choice API Key click edit (pencil icon ) and then go to below of the page 
click Add "Package name And SHA-1 certificate fingerprint" 
and then add this  information and save

Note: It may take up to 5 minutes for settings to take effect

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you enable the Google Maps Android API in your Developer Console and all the APIs that you are using. Another possible cause of this behavior is by using incorrect SHA 1, so make sure you get SHA 1 fingerprint correctly. Check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup) on how to get an API key and SHA 1 fingerprint correctly. For more information, try to follow this [tutorial](http://javapapers.com/android/android-show-current-location-on-map-using-google-maps-api/) on how to use Google Maps Android API.

> Take NOTE: You have to assign Debug API Key in testing, and Release
>   API Key when release APK. Just insert the correct API Key, clean and
>   rebuild your project should be OK. It's suggested to un-install your
>   old app in device before re-load.

Answer (score 0):

Happened the same to me. I just went here:

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/

And created/activated/enabled another key by creating a new project (left pane -> API administration).

They will give you a new key.

It worked for me.